# Is there something like Hadoop, but based on GPU?

Tags: cuda, distributed-computing, gpgpu, multiple-gpu

Is there something like Hadoop, but based on GPU? I would like to do some research on distributed computing. Thank you for your help!

Yik,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mars: A framework for GPU MapReduce comes to mind. Is that what you're thinking? There are other examples using GPUs by a traditional Hadoop system, and running Hadoop on a GPU entirely.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am thinking about GPU MapReduce. I just wanna find an application/software like Hadoop to manage all GPUs in different machines. Could you give me links to papers or examples? so that I can get a clear idea on GPU MapReduce.

Comment: If you want to go this route, you can always use JNI or Hadoop Streaming to run OpenCL (or other GPU Compute) Map & Reduce functions.